# Calculate Cosine Similarity Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I am using Spark Scala to calculate cosine similarity between the Dataframe rows.

Dataframe format is below

```
root
    |-- SKU: double (nullable = true)
    |-- Features: vector (nullable = true)
```

Sample of the dataframe below

```
    +-------+--------------------+
    |    SKU|            Features|
    +-------+--------------------+
    | 9970.0|[4.7143,0.0,5.785...|
    |19676.0|[5.5,0.0,6.4286,4...|
    | 3296.0|[4.7143,1.4286,6....|
    |13658.0|[6.2857,0.7143,4....|
    |    1.0|[4.2308,0.7692,5....|
    |  513.0|[3.0,0.0,4.9091,5...|
    | 3753.0|[5.9231,0.0,4.846...|
    |14967.0|[4.5833,0.8333,5....|
    | 2803.0|[4.2308,0.0,4.846...|
    |11879.0|[3.1429,0.0,4.5,4...|
    +-------+--------------------+
```

I tried to transpose the matrix and check the following mentioned links.[Apache Spark Python Cosine Similarity over DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43921636/apache-spark-python-cosine-similarity-over-dataframes), [calculating-cosine-similarity-by-featurizing-the-text-into-vector-using-tf-idf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645231/calculating-cosine-similarity-by-featurizing-the-text-into-vector-using-tf-idf) But I believe there is a better solution

I am tried the below sample code

```
val irm = new IndexedRowMatrix(inClusters.rdd.map {
  case (v,i:Vector) => IndexedRow(v, i)


}).toCoordinateMatrix.transpose.toRowMatrix.columnSimilarities
```

But I got the below error

```
Error:(80, 12) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Row
      case (v,i:Vector) => IndexedRow(v, i)
```

I checked the following Link [Apache Spark: How to create a matrix from a DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567989/apache-spark-how-to-create-a-matrix-from-a-dataframe) But can't do it using Scala

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `DataFrame.rdd`  returns `RDD[Row]` not `RDD[(T, U)]`. You have to pattern match the `Row` or directly extract interesting parts.
- `ml` `Vector` used with `Datasets` since Spark 2.0 is not the same as `mllib` `Vector` use by old API. You have to convert it to use with `IndexedRowMatrix`.
- Index has to be `Long` not string.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val irm = new IndexedRowMatrix(inClusters.rdd.map {
  Row(_, v: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector) => 
    org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors.fromML(v)
}.zipWithIndex.map { case (v, i) => IndexedRow(i, v) })
```

Comment: I update the answers for my question, but Is there any way to do it end-to-end using Dataframes?